# Django admin - Disable user deletion

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a django app in which I want to disable user deletion in admin. I have tried to disable actions and setting delete permission to false. But none of them worked.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    actions = None
```

**OR**

```
    def has_delete_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

**OR**

```
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(UserProfileAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

But when I'm using the UserAdmin to add a inline to user information, it is working fine. So please suggest me a way to disable user deletion in django admin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are overriding `has_add_permission` to disable deletion? Also, its better to disable deletion action globally and explicitly add to wherever it's required

Comment: I'm sorry. It is actually `has_delete_permission`. I made a mistake here. And about disabling deletion action, site-wide is a good idea. But when we open an user entry, there will a delete option in the submit-row(save button row). How to disable it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Overriding `ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission` should do the trick, your invoking signature is incorrect, it's missing an `obj` parameter

```
class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None): # note the obj=None
        return False
```

Furthermore, simply `return False` prevents all staffs including administrator from deleting items in the Django Admin, you may want to just tweak `User/Group` permissions to prevent those staff you don't want them to delete an `User()`, by removing their `delete_userprofile` and `delete_user` permissions.

Comment: I want to disable delete permission for super_user itself. Also `has_delete_permission` didn't show any effect.

Comment: @arulmr it's strange, have you registered `UserProfileAdmin` correctly   and there is no overriding of the Admin templates? Try to put an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the `has_delete_permission()` before the `return` clause to ensure it gets invoked.

Comment: I'm giving my code below:
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
        return False

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)`

But **pdb** was not invoked. What is the mistake here? I think code format will not be good in this comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @arulmr I've no idea, you need to spot the actual `ModelAdmin` and Admin templates used to know why `has_delete_permission` is not invoked in `User` change form

Comment: It is working fine in all other apps but not working in my current app only. So I accept your answer.

Comment: In hopes this answer will come up for someone else googling the error message I got, here's what I googled that *didn't* find this answer, which *did* solve my problem:

"""
django "has_delete_permission() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"
"""

Answer (score -2):

If your goal is to permanently remove the "Delete" button from the bottom of all admin change forms, you can do so by modifying the file `.../django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py`.

In particular, replace the lines:

```
    'show_delete_link': (not is_popup and context['has_delete_permission']
                          and (change or context['show_delete'])),
```

with:

```
    'show_delete_link': False,
```

and no admin change forms should show the Delete button in the bottom left.

Comment: Editing the django source files will affect all other applications. But I want to achieve this in my current application only.

Comment: yeah, what if you want to upgrade your django?